# Reuse query SqlExpression cause System.ArgumentException The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

With OrmLite ServiceStack, I did query Select list and Count total like this:

```
public async Task<OrmInvoice> OrmTest(int Id)
    {
        var q = OrmDb.From<OrmInvoice>().Where(o => o.Id == Id);
        var rs1 = await OrmDb.SelectAsync(q);
        var rs2 = await OrmDb.CountAsync(q);

        var q2 = q.Clone(); //try to clone            
        var rs3 = await OrmDb.CountAsync(q2);

        return null;
    }
```

i tested with only rs1 and rs2 => error
try to Clone , rs3 => same error

```
Caught System.ArgumentException

System.ArgumentException: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Validate
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add
  at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadCommandExtensions.SetParameters
```

I'm stuck and don't know why this issue occurs, from base of ormlite ? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you resolve this?  It just started happening to me this morning using OrmLite

Answer (score 0):

You should clear parameters before the second query.

Comment: i can't find any .Clear or something in ormlite servicestack for try fix this issue.
Can you suggest me some key to research Clear parameter ?